# Radio button clicked with label

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have multiple radio buttons. In the code that i have they are different pictures corresponding with different functions.

The user has to know which radio button is clicked. Therefor i'm trying to find a way to change the background of the radio button after it has been clicked. 
In order for the code to work the `<label>` has to stay arround the `<input>` tag.

```
 <div class="radio-toolbar">

        <label class="BottomLeft">
            <input id="tech" type="radio" ng-model="SelectedLayout" value="BottomLeft" />
        </label>

        <label class="BottomRight">
            <input id="tech" type="radio" ng-model="SelectedLayout" value="BottomRight" />
        </label>

        <label class="Dual">
            <input id="tech" type="radio" ng-model="SelectedLayout" value="Dual" />
        </label>

        <label class="DualRight">
            <input id="tech" type="radio" ng-model="SelectedLayout" value="DualRight" />
        </label>

        <label class="Duplex">
            <input id="tech" type="radio" ng-model="SelectedLayout" value="Duplex" />
        </label>

        <label class="Custom">
            <input id="tech" type="radio" ng-model="SelectedLayout" value="Custom" />
        </label>
    </div>
```

Here's the [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8gkc6e58/)

Comment: Why are you using the same `id` for all of your inputs?  The whole point of an `id` is that it allows you to look up elements by their `id`.  But that only works if your `id`s are unique.

Comment: Id should always be unique

Comment: I have a piece of code where I get the element by the id. Since they all have to correspond with each other I used the same ID. It's not the perfect way but i worked with the code that was necessary  'initDropDown(document.getElementById('tech'));'

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: Instead of using the same ID (Which, as pointed out, must be unique to qualify as correct HTML) use a class and get the elements based on classname.

Comment: I will do that thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$('input[type=radio]')
    .on('click', function() {
        var $label = $(this).closest('label');
        $('label').not($label).css('background-color', 'green');
        $label.css('background-color', '#2C8BDE');
});
```

Here is the [`FIDDLE`](http://jsfiddle.net/8gkc6e58/2/).

> Also, you must have unique `ID`'s in html.

Comment: Thank you! Thanks for the advice. I will change the ID's.

Answer (score 0):

To work your labels , your code should look like this.The problem is that , you cannot have same ID for all elements. ID is unique and if you want to work with label , you have to put `for="#"` attribute in your `<label></label>` element.So , remember `<label></label>` goes with `for=""` attribute , and that `for=""` attribute works with the id in the `<input />` tag.And I've made your radio buttons non-multiple , so remove `name=""` attribute to work as multiple.

```
  <div class="radio-toolbar">

            <label for="first">
                Tech<input id="first" type="radio" ng-model="SelectedLayout" name="radioButton"  value="BottomLeft" />
            </label>

            <label for="second">
                AnotherOne<input id="second" type="radio" ng-model="SelectedLayout" name="radioButton" value="BottomRight" />
            </label>

            <label for="third">
                Third<input id="third" type="radio" ng-model="SelectedLayout"  name="radioButton" value="Dual" />
            </label>

            <label for="fourth">
                Fourth<input id="fourth" type="radio" ng-model="SelectedLayout" name="radioButton" value="DualRight" />
            </label>

            <label for="fifth">
                Fifth<input id="fifth" type="radio" ng-model="SelectedLayout" name="radioButton" value="Duplex" />
            </label>

            <label for="sixth">
                Sixth<input id="sixth" type="radio" ng-model="SelectedLayout" name="radioButton" value="Custom" />
            </label>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/8gkc6e58/4/).I have changed backgorund color checked radio button to orange with jquery

```
 $('input[type=radio]')
    .on('click', function() {
        var $label = $(this).closest('label');
        $('label').not($label).css('background-color', 'green');
        $label.css('background-color', '#2C8BDE');
});
```